# How to make Apache Common Logging Write to Specific Disc Log File

Tags: java

I am using Apache Common Logging in Desktop Application.

```
private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Utils.class);
```

How can I direct, Apache Common Logging to write to disc log file, when I perform

```
log.error(null, exp);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commons Logging is basically a wrapper around either Java logging (java.util.logging) or the log4j library. You will need to configure whichever underlying library you are using.

In your example, if I was using log4j (and I generally prefer it to the Java logging system), I would use something like:

log4j.logger.com.mypackage.MyClass = ERROR, FILEA

To specify a file to output to.

It would be worthwhile reading an [introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Define appenders in the configuration file. For Log4J sample take a look at
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Examplelog4jConfigurationFile.htm

For java logging, take a look at
http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/hunter_logging.html